# center the dots of the unorder list in html

Tags: html, css

I have tried to fix this, but the bullets are staying to the left, but text is formatting correctly. I used
`text-align: center` , but that only formats the text, and not the bullets. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .toolbar {
          text-align: center;
        }
    </style> 
    <body>
      <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Header Label</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>first</li>
          <li>second</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should look like below (here * represents bullets):

```
                                * first
                                * second
                                * third
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by centering the bullets?

Comment: bullets should be aligned in center & vertically and then text should be after them

Comment: Do you want your H1 in the center of the page or the left side of the page?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#inner {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#outer {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>Header Label</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to specify `div` for that than you can use `margin: 0 auto` and `display` property for centering your content and centering your `list` in single line!

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

```
.toolbar {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```css
.toolbar {
      width: fit-content;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Header Label</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Way 2:

```css
h1 {
   text-align: center;
}

ul {
      width: fit-content;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Header Label</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex to align the items inside the toolbar to the center and then the ul text to the left. Is that what you need?

```css
.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
ul {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
<h1>Header Label</h1>
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .toolbar {
          text-align: center;
        }
        ul {
          list-style-position: inside;
          text-align: left;
          padding-left: 0;
       display: inline-block;
        }
    </style> 
    <body>
      <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Header Label</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>first</li>
          <li>second</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```